# Why am I getting a duplicate symbol when declaring this public member function in another file? (C++)

Tags: c++, scope, duplicates, symbols

Alright, so I've been setting up a pretty simple class in C++ to handle changing the functions I want to use with GLUT. But, I am having trouble when defining one of the public member functions in the .cpp file that corresponds to the header file containing the class definition.

When I define the class in the header file, I don't get any compilation errors. But when I define the function in the .cpp file, with the header file included, I get an error "duplicate symbol `SystemModule::setupGlutFunctions`". As far as I can tell, I'm using the correct syntax for defining this function in a separate file than the original. Here is the code:

```
#include "system.h"

void SystemModule::setupGlutFunctions()
{
glutDisplayFunc(displayFunc);
glutReshapeFunc(reshapeFunc);
glutMouseFunc(mouseFunc);
glutKeyboardFunc(keyboardFunc);
glutSpecialFunc(specialFunc);
glutIdleFunc(idleFunc);
glutMotionFunc(motionFunc);
glutPassiveMotionFunc(passiveMotionFunc);

return;
}
```

The actual contents of the code don't really matter, as that compiles fine when declared in the .h file, inside the class definition. But when I try to define the function in a separate .cpp file, I get the error. It's a public function.

I am using Xcode on Mac OS X 10.5. Has anyone else gotten this error before? And can anyone tell me if I'm doing something wrong in the syntax or if I have to do something special in Xcode for this to work?

Much obliged,
E.

Comment: what does the declaration look like in the header? You didn't stub it out in the header or anything, did you?

Comment: "void setupGlutFunctions();" is how it looks.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a *linker* error, not a *compiler* error, which suggests that somehow you're compiling two different copies of the `setupGlutFunctions` code and trying to link them together.  This could either be because you have two different files with the same implementation that are being linked together.

One possible candidate - are you `#include`-ing the .cpp file at the end of the .h file?  If so, any file that `#include`s your header file will get their own copy of the `setupGlutFunctions` implementation.  At link time, the linker will see that the function has multiple different definitions, and will raise an error because it's not sure which one of the many identical implementations you were looking for.

Another possible candidate (mentioned above by @DougT) - if you accidentally provided an implementation in the header, like this:

```
class SystemModule {
public:
    void setupGlutFunctions() {
        /* ... */
    }
};
```

Then you have actually defined two implementations of the function - one in the header and one in the .cpp file.  Changing this to read

```
class SystemModule {
public:
    void setupGlutFunctions();
};
```

could fix this.

Comment: Well, I'm not including the .cpp file in the .h file. This is how the function is declared in the header file:
"void setupGlutFunctions();"

And when I add the definition to this declaration, it compiles just fine. Did I screw up the function signatures or something?

Comment: @E_12- Can you provide more info about the error you're getting?  Where is it saying that the symbols have previously been defined?  And have you done a clean build in the meantime?

Comment: I've done a clean build. The code is the same, just tacked onto the declaration:
`void setupGlutFunctions()
  {
   glutDisplayFunc(displayFunc);
   glutReshapeFunc(reshapeFunc);
   glutMouseFunc(mouseFunc);
   glutKeyboardFunc(keyboardFunc);
   glutSpecialFunc(specialFunc);
   glutIdleFunc(idleFunc);
   glutMotionFunc(motionFunc);
   glutPassiveMotionFunc(passiveMotionFunc);
 
   return;
  }`
is how it looks in the header file. Exactly the same as the other file. This builds with no errors or warnings.

Comment: @E_12- What specific error are you getting from the linker about multiple declarations?  How many files have their own definition of this code?

Comment: "ld: duplicate symbol SystemModule::setupGlutFunctions()       in /Users/evan/Desktop/opengl/build/opengl.build/Debug/opengl.build/Objects-normal/i386/system.o and /Users/evan/Desktop/opengl/build/opengl.build/Debug/opengl.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status"

Sorry, I'm fairly new to this site, I don't fully understand how the text formatting works yet.

And just one file has the definition of this code: system.cpp, the code for which is in the original question. But the function is declared in system.h and "opengl" is the name of the project.

Comment: Additionally, main.cpp includes "system.cpp". That might be relevant.

Comment: @E_12- Okay, that error is somehow telling you that you have an implementation of `SystemModule::setupGlutFunctions` in both your `main.cpp` and `system.cpp` files.  This is good to know!  The question now is how your one definition is getting into both `main.cpp` and `system.cpp`.  By any chance, are you `#include`-ing `system.cpp` into your `main.cpp` file?  If so, that would give you exactly the behavior you're seeing here.  Typically, one does not `#include` cpp files into each other, but instead `#include`s the headers and then lets the linker resolve everything.

Comment: Ah, yes, that is exactly what I'm doing. When I changed main.cpp to include system.h instead of system.cpp, it built just fine. Thanks a lot! Totally noobin' it up in here.

Comment: @E_12- No worries!  I'm glad I was able to help out!